# Is it possible to export an OpenVZ machine and use it after in another virtualization tool?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, openvz, vmware-vmdk

I'm planning to use OpenVZ in an old machine I have at home.

I want to know if a dumped OpenVZ instance image can be exported to other formats (like VirtualBox or Vmware).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not AFAIK but you should be able to use bare-metal tools like mondorescue.org or clonezilla.org to back up the VM and restore it to another VM system

Comment: You mean copying everything in the file system, creating a virtual machine and pasting everything, right?

Comment: with a bit more research into OpenVZ I see that its basically a partitioned kernel. There are no disk images in use, its a directory on your system. I suggest tar/untar and create a new "/etc/vz/conf/VM.conf" file with the new directory. 
Hope that helps some more.